# php img src gives wrong url

Tags: php, html

```
echo '<img src="'.$row['image_url'].'" class="img-thumbnail">';
```

this gives me the link of

```
http://localhost/events-uploads/5bc9f6074a2788.39011795.png'
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/cinematheque-app/events-uploads/5bc9f6074a2788.39011795.png
```

that is why the image that I uploaded wont show...

How do I show the proper url?

I added the 'cinematheque-app' keyword whenever I save in the database so for example a URL gets save like this "cinematheque-app/events-uploads/5bc9f6074a2788.39011795.png"

but whenever I add it to the img src using this

```
echo '<img src="'.$row['image_url'].'" class="img-thumbnail">';
```

it gives me http://localhost/cinematheque-app/cinematheque-app/events-uploads/5bc9f6074a2788.39011795.png

I am saving it like this...

```
$file =$_FILES['image_url'];
$fileName = $_FILES['image_url']['name'];
$fileTmpName = $_FILES['image_url']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['image_url']['size'];
$fileError = $_FILES['image_url']['error'];
$fileType = $_FILES['image_url']['type'];
$fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));



if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
    if ($fileError === 0){
        if($fileSize > 20000) {
            $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
            $fileDestination = '../events-uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
            $actual_url = "cinematheque-app".trim( $fileDestination, "." );

            move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);

            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO events (title, time, date, branch, description, price, status, created_at, image_url) 
            VALUES ('$title', '$time', '$date', '$branch', '$description', '$price', '$status', '$created_at', '$actual_url')") or die($mysqli->error);

        header("Location: ../manage-events.php?added=success"); 
        }
        else {
            //File is too big
        }
    }else{
        //There is some error
    }
}       
}
```

I am getting it like this...

```
                    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($events_per_page)) { ?>
                    <tr class="table table-borderless table-sm text-center">
                       <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?> </td>
                       <td><?php echo date("h:ia", strtotime($row['time'])); ?> </td>
                       <td><?php echo date("M-d-Y", strtotime($row['date'])); ?> </td>
                       <td><?php echo $row['branch']; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
                       <td>
                       <?php
                        // $system_url = "cinematheque-app";
                        // $removed_front_slash_url = trim( $row['image_url'], "/" );
                        // $actual_url = trim( $row['image_url'], "." );

                        echo '<img src="'.$row['image_url'].'" class="img-fluid">'; 
                        // echo $row['image_url'];
                       ?>
                       </td>
```

querying of the data

```
$total_events = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from events") or die($mysqli->error);
```

[image: The events table]

this is where I make that transition...

```
$number_of_results = $total_events->num_rows;
$results_per_page  = 4;
$number_of_pages   = ceil($number_of_results / $results_per_page);

$this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$results_per_page;
$sql="SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT " .$this_page_first_result . "," .  $results_per_page;
$events_per_page = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);
```

I figured it out!

I used

```
echo '<img src="/'.$row['image_url'].'" class="img-fluid">'; 
$actual_url = "cinematheque-app".trim( $fileDestination, "." );
```

Comment: OK. Did you have a question? It look like someone stored the wrong thing in the database.

Comment: because your `$row['image_url']` contains only *'http://localhost/events-uploads/5bc9f6074a2788.39011795.png'*

Comment: no, actually it contains events-uploads/5bc9f6074a2788.39011795.png, how do I get the proper url?

Comment: No, it doesn't. not unless you're querying the wrong table.

Comment: I tried adding the 'cinematheque-app' keyword whenever I save it to the database so it goes like this 'cinematheque-app/events-uploads/5bc9f6074a2788.39011795.png' that is the URL I am saving in the database but whenever I put that in the img src, it is giving me 'http://localhost/cinematheque-app/cinematheque-app/events-uploads/5bc9fbbb2f7258.09589508.png'

Comment: Show us how you add the data to the database and show us the code for retrieval.

Comment: I edited it and added to the post..

Comment: Can you show us actually what is stored in the database? Do you have a table view?

Comment: Show us the query for the retrieval of the data.

Comment: there you go...

Comment: FYI [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: it is just for a school project, I dont think they would go that deep... they didn't even taught us how to code in public school, we just have to study it ourselves..

Comment: Where is the select query?

Comment: in the post, I added it @JayBlanchard

Comment: The query is `$total_events` the rows come from `$events_per_page`. Where do you make that transition?

Comment: You do understand the one answer is giving you a work-around, not the answer for why you're not getting this properly from the database.

Comment: You show what you call the transition, but you never show `$events_per_page` in that.

Comment: I am getting it properly from the database, what should I save in the database? the whole URL which has the localhost/cinematheque-app/events-uploads./filename.ext ???

Comment: im sorry, I pasted it twice, I fixed it now..

Comment: yes because I am using pagination... the proper url is `cinematheque-app/events-uploads/5bc9f6074a2788.39011795.png` but if I store that, it gives me `cinematheque-app/cinematheque-app/events-uploads/5bc9f6074a2788.39011795.png`

Comment: Then you're re-appending `cinematheque-app/` somewhere in the code. BTW, This is not your originally reported problem.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes I did, thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I show the proper url?

You store the proper URL in the database OR you query the right table.

Comment: Isn't this passive-aggressive?

Comment: No, it is direct @NiMusco, given what we know at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

try adding the name of the folder containing your files like this :

```
echo '<img src="cinematheque-app/'.$row['image_url'].'" class="img-thumbnail">';
```

in your database, save only the filename without paths or folder names, and add folder names in the html.

Comment: He should be able to get the entire path from the database.

Comment: this worked! I just save the file name which was "5bc9f6074a2788.39011795.png"

and in the 



        echo '<img src="events-uploads/'.$row['image_url'].'" class="img-thumbnail">';

Comment: But that doesn't explain why you're not getting the full path from the database